# Xcode / Obj C - How can I add a touchdown event to a disabled control

Tags: xcode

I have a disabled toggle button. I'd like to add a touchdown event to the disabled control. So when it's tapped - an alert shows why it's disabled. I'm using Obj-C. Any ideas how I can achieve this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the super view of the control. It probably has to check, if the touch is inside of the control to decide if it should open the alert.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you want to have action but to warn user that button is disabled.

I would suggest two options:

**First**, and mostly elegant is: If you're using `UIButton` subclass, that object is having isSelected boolean that is pretty straight forward, so action on that button pressed is triggered everytime, but you can only check isSelected. So in your action just have negation of previous state: button.isSelected = !button.isSelected and than have checking of selection and present alert.

**Second**, just add one global boolean in that class, set initial state to whatever it is, and negate it on action on that button.

Comment: I'm using a switch/toggle. Any idea why the following does not work 
              UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]

                                   initWithTarget:self

                                   action:@selector(show)];

    

    [self.passwordToggle addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    
-(void)show{ // Show something  }

Comment: If you are using UISwitch, I can recommend that you add action to it, and apply second way of handling lock.